# Proof of equipartition theorem for $i$ not equal to $j$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, virial-theorem

The generalized equipartition theorem (where variables need not be quadratic) states that if $x_i$ is a canonical variable (position or momentum variable), then

$$\left\langle x_i \frac{∂H}{∂x_j}\right\rangle=δ_{ij}\cdot k_BT.$$

[Wikipedia provides proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#General_formulation_of_the_equipartition_theorem) of this for a microcanonical ensemble (for any $i$, $j$) and for a canonical ensemble (ostensibly for $i=j$ only).  However, the case of a canonical ensemble with $i$ not equal to $j$ (i.e., $\langle x_i \, ∂H/∂x_j\rangle =0$) appears to be missing proof.  Is it a simple extension?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proof is almost identical to the one on the Wikipedia page, and can be found e.g. in *Statistical Mechanics* (3rd ed) by RK Pathria and PD Beale, p62. 
We start with 
$$
\left\langle x_i \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle = 
\frac{\int x_i \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_j} e^{-\beta H} d\Gamma}{\int  e^{-\beta H} d\Gamma} .
$$
Integration of the numerator by parts with respect to $x_j$ gives
$$
\int x_i \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_j} e^{-\beta H} d\Gamma
= \int \left[ \frac{1}{\beta} \int \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} e^{-\beta H} dx_j \right] d\Gamma'
$$
where $\Gamma'$ stands for all the coordinates *except* for $x_j$, and a boundary term $x_i e^{-\beta H}$ evaluated at $x_j=\pm\infty$ has been omitted: it is assumed to vanish on the grounds that $H$ becomes infinite whenever $x_j$ becomes infinite (or is bounded by the container walls). The important point is that $\partial x_i/\partial x_j = \delta_{ij}$ which comes out of the integral. That gives us 
$$
k_BT \, \delta_{ij} \int e^{-\beta H} d\Gamma
$$
and the integral cancels with the denominator in the original expression.